# Relationship query is working in controller but not showing in blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I have query like this.

```
$types = Types::where('id', '=', '2')->with('purposes', function ($query) {
       $query->withCount('pool');
})->first();
```

This query works well and i have this foreach. This foreach gives exactly what i want do and it works in controller but not working in blade completely. It gives types_name but count is not working. However when it gives count in controller. What should i do?

```
Foreach($types as $item){
   $item->pool_name;
   $item->pool_purposes_count;
 }
```

Comment: $types is a single entry I believe because of the `->first()`. Why loop?

Comment: You dont need array, you can access by `$types->types_name;`

Comment: You can shorten the where/first with `find(2)`, just add the with before it.

Comment: I fixed the question

Comment: print dd($types); in controller after the query and check if you getting count and paste the screenshot of dd($types)

Comment: first() will get a single result   get() gets an array / collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$item = Types::->with('purposes', function ($query) {
       $query->withCount('pool');
})->find(2);
```

Then you can use, in blade:

```
$item->pool_name;
$item->pool_purposes_count;
```